Change selected Icon in Segmented Button
I'm usingFlutter and try to use Segmented Button. Here my code:
SegmentedButton<int>(
      segments: [
        ButtonSegment(
          value: 0,
          label: Text('Asked'),
        ),
        ButtonSegment(
          value: 1,
          label: Text('Answered'),
        ),
      ],
      selected: {appProvider.indexLoginSegmentedButton},
      onSelectionChanged: (newSelection) {
        appProvider.changeIndexLoginSegmentedButton(newSelection.first);
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        shape: WidgetStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          ),
        ),
        overlayColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
              (Set<WidgetState> states) {
            if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
              return kShrineAppBarPurple.withOpacity(0.08);
            }
            return Colors.transparent;
          },
        ),
        side: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide>(
              (Set<WidgetState> states) {
            if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
              return BorderSide(color: kShrineAppBarPurple, width: 2.0);
            }
            return BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0);
          },
        ),
        foregroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
              (Set<WidgetState> states) {
            if (states.contains(WidgetState.selected)) {
              return kShrineAppBarPurple;
            }
            return Colors.black;
          },
        ),
      ),
    )


ResultsImage
However when I implement it, the selected button displays a checked selected icon. Is it possible to edit/delete it?
However when I implement it, the selected button displays a checked selected icon. Is it possible to edit/delete it?

add this property showSelectedIcon:false  to SegmentedButton to hide selectedIcon.
Add selectedIcon property to add your favourite icon.
selectedIcon property
Widget? icon

An icon that is used to indicate a segment is selected.

showSelectedIcon property
bool showSelectedIcon

Determines if the selectedIcon (usually an icon using Icons.check) is displayed on the selected segments.{...} The default is true, meaning
the selectedIcon will be shown on selected segments.

Link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SegmentedButton/showSelectedIcon.html
